# Selection list to Selected list with double click

Tags: jquery

Im a newbie to the world of jQuery. I have two ul lists. I want to be able to double click on the Select side and have the item cloned/copied to the Selected list.
This is what I have come up with.

```
<form>
    <ul id="selection">
    <li><input type="hidden" id="tid" value="1" />Apple</li>
    <li><input type="hidden" id="tid" value="2" />Orange</li>
    <li><input type="hidden" id="tid" value="3" />Pear</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="selected">
    <li><input type="hidden" id="tid" value="4" />Mango</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

and the jQuery to move the item...

```
$(function () {
    $("form li").dblclick(function(){
        $('#selected').append($('input[type="hidden"]').clone());
    });
});
```

Comment: Invalid markup same `IDs` for multiple elems in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
$(function () {
    $("form li").dblclick(function(){
        $('#selected').append($(this).clone())
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, got it going. Kind of simple, was it not?
That is how you learn I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, but you need to append the whole `li` instead:

```
$("form li").dblclick(function(){
    $('#selected').append($(this).clone());
});
```

See this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6NEwH/)

Answer (score 1):

you should write

```
$(function () {
    $("form li").dblclick(function(){
        $('#selected').append($(this).clone()));
    });
});
```